# p menu bar doesn't has the correctly view responsive

Tags: angular, primeng

I follow this tutorial

[p menuBar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/menubar)

I don't like the default behaviour I want that when the page is restricted it appears the hambuger icon and when I click the menu items are there . Anyone know how  can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I dont use primeNg myself, but it looks like primeNg does not provide a hamburger menu. But I think that you could make use of a [OverlayPanel](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/overlaypanel) (they use it for the sidebar as well) and then use css media queries to show or hide the menu bar or the hamburger menu/ hamburger button.
I hope this gets you going into the right direction.

Edit: You could also have a look at a combination of a overlayPanel with a [menu](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/menu) or a [slide menu](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/slidemenu)

Answer (score 0):

For pmenubar model the menu item has a property called visible,  you can set that properly dynamically based upon your requirement